# ¿Por que no me funciona el while?

Tags: java, while

Tengo que hacer un programa y no me funciona , el principal problema es con el promedio , si lo pongo dentro del `while` me imprime que da todo cero , y  lo pongo afuera del while me salta error

> ("Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"
>   ) y algo sobre la division por cero .

Ahora les dejo el enunciado :

> Dado los sueldos y categorias de empleados se pide obtener .
>   A)Cantidad de sueldos < 10000 en la categoria 1. B)Cantidad de sueldos
>
> > =12000 en la categoira 2 y sueldos <=15000 en la categoria 3. C)Cantidad de sueldos >15000. D)Promedio de los sueldos de cada
> >     categoria . El ejercicio finaliza cunado se ingresa una categoria
> >     igual a 0.

```
int sueldo;
        int categoria = 0;
        int cantidadCate1 = 0;
        int cantidadCate2 = 0;
        int cantidadCate3 = 0;
        int cantidadSueldo = 0;
        int sumatoria1 = 0;
        int sumatoria2 = 0;
        int sumatoria3 = 0;
        int promedio1 = 0;
        int promedio2 = 0;
        int promedio3 = 0;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (categoria != 0) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese categoria : ");
            categoria = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese sueldo : ");
            sueldo = teclado.nextInt();

            if (categoria == 1) {

                if (sueldo < 10000) {
                    cantidadCate1++;

                }

                sumatoria1 += sueldo;
            }

            if (categoria == 2) {

                if (sueldo >= 12000) {

                    cantidadCate2++;
                }

                sumatoria2 += sueldo;
            }

            if (categoria == 3) {

                if (sueldo <= 15000) {

                    cantidadCate3++;

                }

                sumatoria3 += sueldo;
            }

            if (sueldo > 15000) {

                cantidadSueldo++;
            }

            promedio1 = sumatoria1 / cantidadCate1;
            promedio2 = sumatoria2 / cantidadCate2;
            promedio3 = sumatoria3 / cantidadCate3;

        }

        System.out.println("a)Cantidad de sueldos <10000 en la categoria 1 : " + cantidadCate1);
        System.out.println("b1)Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoira 2 : " + cantidadCate2);
        System.out.println("b2)Cantidad de de sueldos <= 15000 en la categoira 3 : " + cantidadCate3);
        System.out.println("c)Cantidad de sueldos > 15000 : " + cantidadSueldo);
        System.out.println("d)Promedio de los sueldos de cada categoria : ");
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 1 : " + promedio1);
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 2 : " + promedio2);
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 3 : " + promedio3);
```

Comment: Me parece que te equivocas en pedir la categoria.  La categoria deberia de ser calculada en base al sueldo.  Ademas, si quieres desplegar el promedio por categoria, debes de asegurarte que la cantidad no sea cero.

Comment: declaras la categoría como 0 y luego nunca la cambias, eso hace que la condición del while porque 0 no es diferente de 0 no sirva y no entre al ciclo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que entre al while `categoria` debe ser diferente de 0 en un principio, puedes ponerle cualquier valor, en este caso yo la eh inicializado con 1.
Los promedios se van a calcular fuera del while, ya que se tiene la sumatoria total de los sueldos, para evitar que cuando pongas 0 te pida el sueldo, eh añadido un pequeño if que se salta los pasos, y al finalizar, para sacar el promedio tu error se debe a la division entre 0, para ello se valida que si la cantidad y la sumatoria deben ser mayores a 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sueldo;
        int categoria = 1; //Aquí inicializas en un valor diferente a 0
        int cantidadCate1 = 0;
        int cantidadCate2 = 0;
        int cantidadCate3 = 0;
        int cantidadSueldo = 0;
        int sumatoria1 = 0;
        int sumatoria2 = 0;
        int sumatoria3 = 0;
        int promedio1 = 0;
        int promedio2 = 0;
        int promedio3 = 0;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (categoria != 0) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese categoria : ");
            categoria = teclado.nextInt();

            if (categoria != 0) {//Este if sirve para que no te pida el sueldo
                System.out.println("Ingrese sueldo : ");
                sueldo = teclado.nextInt();
                if (categoria == 1) {
                    if (sueldo < 10000) {
                        cantidadCate1++;
                    }
                    sumatoria1 += sueldo;
                }
                if (categoria == 2) {
                    if (sueldo >= 12000) {
                        cantidadCate2++;
                    }
                    sumatoria2 += sueldo;
                }
                if (categoria == 3) {
                    if (sueldo <= 15000) {
                        cantidadCate3++;
                    }
                    sumatoria3 += sueldo;
                }
                if (sueldo > 15000) {
                    cantidadSueldo++;
                }
            }
        }

        //Validaciones que no sean divisiones entre 0

        if (sumatoria1 > 0 && cantidadCate1 > 0) {
            promedio1 = sumatoria1 / cantidadCate1;
        }
        if (sumatoria2 > 0 && cantidadCate2 > 0) {
            promedio2 = sumatoria2 / cantidadCate2;
        }
        if (sumatoria3 > 0 && cantidadCate3 > 0) {
            promedio3 = sumatoria3 / cantidadCate3;
        }

        System.out.println("a)Cantidad de sueldos <10000 en la categoria 1 : " + cantidadCate1);
        System.out.println("b1)Cantidad de sueldos >= 12000 en la categoira 2 : " + cantidadCate2);
        System.out.println("b2)Cantidad de de sueldos <= 15000 en la categoira 3 : " + cantidadCate3);
        System.out.println("c)Cantidad de sueldos > 15000 : " + cantidadSueldo);
        System.out.println("d)Promedio de los sueldos de cada categoria : ");
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 1 : " + promedio1);
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 2 : " + promedio2);
        System.out.println("Promedio de la categoria 3 : " + promedio3);
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono poniendo categoria = 1 .

Answer (score 2):

Anteriormente te había comentado que en el caso en el cual no se seleccione alguna categoria los valores de `cantidadCate1, cantidadCate2 y cantidadCate3`, tendrían el valor de cero, lo cual provocaría el error:

> ("Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by
>   zero" )

Para esto debes validar solo realizar la operación cuando no tiene valor de cero cualquiera de las variables:

```
    if(cantidadCate1 > 0)
    promedio1 = sumatoria1 / cantidadCate1;
    if(cantidadCate2 > 0)
    promedio2 = sumatoria2 / cantidadCate2;
    if(cantidadCate3 > 0)
    promedio3 = sumatoria3 / cantidadCate3;
```

Comment: Puse los if pero no funciona esta igual :/

Comment: En que linea  se muestra el problema? @computer96

Comment: En la parte del promedio , pero ahora funciona Gracias .

Comment: hehe tal vez no se había construido (build) tu programa @computer96